# New row by enter button in input (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have text input in my View

Here is code

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Detail, new { @class = "greeting2", data_bind = "textInput: Detail", id = "Detail", placeholder = "Описание" })
```

And  where i show text via KnockoutJS

Here is code of span

```
<p style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 40px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 40px; text-align: center;"><span data-bind="text: Detail"/>
                </p>
```

Here is knockoutJS code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModel() {
        this.Greeting = ko.observable('');
        this.Detail = ko.observable('');
    };

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

</script>
```

When I write text all okay and spaces are checking. But when I click enter text will go on new row. But it in one row, like on screenshot.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZJdV.png)

How I can make new row by enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually just a styling issue, adding `white-space: pre-wrap` to styling for the `span` element should fix the issue:

```
<p style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 40px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 40px; text-align: center;"><span data-bind="text: Detail" style="white-space: pre-wrap" /></p>
```